# How to find critical point

Tags: calculus

[image]

In the above question *f'(x) is zero at x = 0* , discontinuous at *x = 1* and not differentiable at *x = 2* . Therefore, the function must have 3 critical points but the answer is *A* that is only *1 critical point*.

Please explain the reason behind why only 1 critical point.

Comment: I am afraid that the definition of a critical point is not always the same in different parts of the world. Also, how can $f'$ be zero at $1$?

Comment: critical point must be in the domain. What is not true for $x=\pm 1$

Comment: @imranfat because the critical point is $x=0$.

Comment: @imranfat sorry, f'(x)  = 0 at x = 0. I have edited it

Comment: How do arrive at the 'Therefore' conclusion? (It's not differentiable at $x=\pm 2$, by the way)

Comment: @Thomas then how to conclude the number of critical points.

Comment: If it's the number of zeros of $f^\prime$, then by counting these. You arrive at $1$. If it's the joint number of minima, maxima and zeros of $f^\prime$ you need a different reasoning. But I still don't get how you arrive at $3$.

Comment: @Thomas My desmos screwed up...

Comment: @Arnaldo thanks. But then also we have 2 critical points those are 4 and 0

Comment: @user411518: That depends on the way how you define critical point. As far as I know, the most common definition is: the roots of $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Why should $4$ be a critical point??? You have now claimed several times that there has to be a certain (varying) number of critical points but are not willing or able to  provide _any_ reason for this. Are you rollng dice?

Comment: @Thomas ohk. I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard modern Calculus textbooks (at least the ones commonly used in the United States), a critical point is a point of the domain where the derivative is either zero or doesn't exist. Thus there are two types of critical points.

For the function $\displaystyle{f(x) = \frac{\left|x^2-4\right|}{x^2-1}}$

- $f^\prime(x) = 0\,$ only at $x = 0$.

  The domain of $f$ is $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \ne \pm 1\}$.

  The only values in the domain of $f$ where $f^\prime(x)$ fails to exist are the values $x = \pm 2$.

Therefore $f$ has $3$ critical points, namely $x = 0,\; x = \pm 2$.